# How can I make a two-color based table on Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

So, I'm trying to make a 2-color based table that looks like [image: table]

but with different colors.

When I put Make new table I get[image: this]

Where is the second color? How do I make a **template** of a table that has a color other than grey and another color? For example, Black and white.

Note: I'm mainly trying to get rid of the grey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the 2nd picture and spot the `Apply formatting to`. Select from the menu `Odd banded rows` or `Even banded rows` whichever that has the colour you want to change. Then, select the fill colour from the 2nd colour menu, which you labelled as "one color" in the picture above. Confirm your changes.

To save your changes as a new table style, or as you know it as a template, expand the Table Style list and pick `New table style` and apply whatever changes you prefer. It will be added to the table styles list in the `Table Tools \ Design` tab from the Ribbon.